# Como corrigir esse erro Json

Tags: python, json, api

Estou coletando dados de uma Api que me retoma as informações em um dicionario Json pra joga numa appweb so que o servidor me da esse erro como posso fazer para corrigi isso?

Erro que esta dando:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dalmo/mysite/models/database.py", line 25, in <module>
    BancoDados.total()
  File "/home/dalmo/mysite/models/database.py", line 23, in total
    return BancoDados.Expert() + BancoDados.TS1()
  File "/home/dalmo/mysite/models/database.py", line 10, in Expert
    respo = json.loads(str(url.text))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py", line 348, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
>>>
```

Meu codigo:

```
import requests
import json

class BancoDados:

    def Expert():

        url = requests.get('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/Flights.aspx?'
            'apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=7e5dcd44-1fb5-49cc-bc2c-a9aab1f6a856')
        respo = json.loads(str(url.text))
        return(respo)



    def TS1():

        url = requests.get('http://infinite-flight-public-api.cloudapp.net/v1/Flights.aspx?'
            'apikey=78879b1d-3ba3-47de-8e50-162f35dc6e04&sessionid=6a04ffe8-765a-4925-af26-d88029eeadba')
        respo = json.loads(str(url.text))
        return(respo)

    def total ():
        return BancoDados.Expert() + BancoDados.TS1()

BancoDados.total()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você deve colocar o erro completo com traceback, em formato texto, e não imagem. [Edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/343525/edit) a pergunta e adicione o erro em texto. Coloque também a parte relevante do seu código.

Answer (score 1):

Esse erro ocorre quando a primeira letra da string não é válida em JSON.

É muito comum quando você acha que o site vai retornar JSON, mas ele retorna HTML por algum motivo, pois HTMLs geralmente começam com algo assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE ...
```

Testando com `json.loads()`:

```
>>> json.loads('<!DOCTYPE')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Como pode ver é exatamente o mesmo erro que você está recebendo. Para conferir se é o caso, tente exibir de alguma forma o conteúdo da variável, antes do erro:

```
print(url.text)
```